# Mysql on ubuntu root password dissapeared somehow? Password no more required for mysql root?

Tags: mysql, password, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql loses its root password](https://serverfault.com/questions/283549/mysql-loses-its-root-password)

I am sure i have mysql server installed on localhost with ubuntu with root user and required password. I have continued my daily developing job and suddenly password for root is no more required? Somehow, suddenly. I am aware that I did not change any settings related to mysql.

Comment: and i see now, i am not onlyone http://serverfault.com/questions/283549/mysql-loses-its-root-password/433386#433386

Comment: You do realize you just said that you are posting a question that has already been asked. This is not allowed.

Comment: I bet I just have encountered security issue related to Ruby On Rails framework. Sorry for any inconvenience. I have located steps which lead to password lost.

Report was submitted to core team. I will be back, once this security bug is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that the root password can be saved in `~/my.cnf` which would bypass the requirement to enter a root password on the command line.

Similarly, if you were so inclined, you can have phpmyadmin auto login without a password as any user too.

You may not have made these changes but perhaps another developer using the same machine did.

Passwords don't just 'reset' themselves without user intervention.

Comment: I bet I just have encountered security issue related to Ruby On Rails framework. Sorry for any inconvenience. I have located steps which lead to password lost.

Report was submitted to core team. I will be back, once this security bug is confirmed.